# Definition of derivative with integrals

Tags: calculus

Can we say that $$\int_0^t u_t(x,t,s) \, ds = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_0^{t+h} u(x,t+h,s)-u(x,t,s) \, ds}{h}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is true if both $u(x,t,s)$ and $u_t(x,t,s)$ are continuous for $t$ and $s$. That is if both $u(x,t,s)$ and $u_t(x,t,s)$ are continuous then $$g(t)=\int_{0}^{t}u(x,t,s)~ds$$ is differentiable and $$g'(t)=\int_{0}^{t}u_t(x,t,s)~ds.$$

So, $$\int_{0}^{t}u_t(x,t,s)~ds=\lim \limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\int_{0}^{t}u(x,t+h,s)~ds -\int_{0}^{t}u(x,t,s)~ds}{h}\\=\lim \limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\int_{0}^{t}\left( u(x,t+h,s)~ds -u(x,t,s)\right) ~ds}{h}.$$